# no reaction to incoming MQTT message

Tags: arduino, mqtt, publish-subscribe

I have a simple setup of a wemos d1 mini with a button and some LED's. It can send and receive MQTT messages and should act upon them.

I want that it sends "11" when pressing the button and light the LED's when receiving a specific message - "21" in this case.

It all seems to be working alright, the message is going out and it is reporting that it "sees" "21" when that message comes in. But then it skips the `IF` statement where I compare the incoming message with a string. They both print out the same, but the `IF`comparison seems to say they are not. This is done in the callback loop.

Could anyone point me to where i go wrong?

```
long lastMsg = 0;
char msg[50];
int value = 0;
char* msgIN;
String msgIN_trigger;
char* msgOUT;
String boxID = "1";
int boxID_len = boxID.length() + 1;
String clientID = "rememberbox " + boxID;
int clientID_len = clientID.length() + 1;

void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
  Serial.print("Message arrived: [");
  Serial.print(topic);
  Serial.print("] ");
  String msgIN = "";
  msgIN += (char *)payload;
  String msgString = msgIN;
  Serial.print(msgIN.substring(0,2));
  Serial.println("/");


    if (msgString == msgIN_trigger) {
      Serial.println("message is for me!");
      Serial.println("wake up MP3 player");
      myMP3.wakeUp();
      Serial.println("play track 5");
      myMP3.play(5);
      Serial.println("confetti!!!");
      confetti();
      Serial.println("and fade to black");
      for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LEDS; i++) {
        leds[i] = CRGB::Black;
      }
      FastLED.show();
      delay(7500);
      myMP3.sleep();
      message_out = false;
      Serial.println("message_out = false");
      Serial.println("");
    }

    Serial.println("nothing intended for me");
    Serial.print("only reacting to message: ");
    Serial.print(msgIN_trigger);
    Serial.println("/");
    Serial.println("");
}
```

Comment: Which `if` statement? Please trim the code down to a minimal viable testcase so we don't need to wade through all of it to find what you are talking about.

Comment: This is trivial debugging. Print the strings you are comparing before the comparison, that will tell you.

Comment: done. sorry. last question somebody asked me to post my full code.

Comment: @Gambit Support. Thats what I have done in the code. It's all printed out and shows me that the msgString is "21" and msgIN_trigger is also "21". Still when then calling: ```if (msgString == msgIN_trigger)```, it still goes straight to the "else" statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an operand to try and compare two Strings...that can lead to flaky operation.  Try this

```
if (strcmp(msgString, msgIN_trigger) == 0) {
   ...
}
```

This is what I use and it seems to work fine.